# Return sorted inner types inferred from passed generic arguments with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that accepts generic arguments and returns their inner values. See this example for a brief idea.

```
interface Outer<V extends {}> { 
    data: V
};

declare function foo<V>(values: Outer<{}>[]): V[];

const [d1, d2] = foo([{data: {a: {x: "a"}}}, {data: {b: "b"}}]);

console.log(d1.a.x); // no err, TS knows `d1` is `{a: {x: "a"}}}`
console.log(d2.b);   // no err, TS knows `d2` is `{b: "b"}`
```

The point is that I want TypeScript to know, that if I pass `Outer<A>, Outer<B>` that the result would be `[A, B]`. Not `(A|B)[]`. I need to keep the order so Vector is desirable.

The call should look like

```
foo(outerA, outerB);
foo([outerA, outerB]); // this would also work I guess
```

Real example:

```
type Outer<T>;
type A;
type B;

const a: Outer<A>;
const b: Outer<B>;

const result = foo([b, a]);
// result is of type `[B, A]`
```

This is what I came up with so far. I tried to leverage input indexes to infer the value based on it. But it gives me array with union types (`(A|B)[]`) as a result, not individual types `[A, B]`.

```
declare function foo
  <D extends {}, K, T extends { [key in keyof K]: Outer<D> }>(arg: T):
  { [KK in keyof T]: T[KK] extends Outer<infer DD> ? DD : never };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get discrete generics from an array, so this kind of approach won't work. However, you can manually specify separate generic types for the function

```
interface Outer<V extends {}> { 
    data: V
};

declare function foo<A>(a: Outer<A>): [A];
declare function foo<A, B>(a: Outer<A>, b: Outer<B>): [A, B];
// ... and so on

const [d1, d2] = foo({data: {a: {x: "a"}}}, {data: {b: "b"}});
```